# Error - Unfortunately, Main Activity has stopped

Tags: android, classnotfoundexception

I am starting to learn to develop app´s to Android systems. 
I was tryng to execute a simple Hello World app on Netbeans, but I got this "Error - Unfortunately, Main Activity has stopped."... I don´t have a clue why...

The code is as follows...

mainactivity.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import br.com.bssotware.teste.R;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }
}
```

And the main.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World, MainActivity"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

When I execute it, I´ve got this log errors:

```
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{br.com.bssotware.teste/br.com.bssotware.teste.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.bssotware.teste.MainActivity
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1983)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: br.com.bssotware.teste.MainActivity
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1053)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1974)
20:48:52.609    940 br.com.bssotware.teste  ERROR   AndroidRuntime      ... 11 more
```

Android manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="br.com.bssotware.teste"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <application android:label="@string/app_name" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
        <activity android:name="MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: The error is `ClassNotFoundException: br.com.bssotware.teste.MainActivity` do you use proguard? Please make sure that your java file is called `MainActivity.java` and not `mainactivity.java` and also that there is the line `package br.com.bssotware.teste;` present

Comment: Have you defined this `MainActivity` in `AndroidManifest.xml`? If not, please do.

Comment: No I am not using proguard.

Comment: I extended my comment please check the other parts

Comment: Yes, there is this line at the beggining... "import br.com.bssotware.teste;"
Also, it is always called "MainActivity"... actually, this code was made by the Netbeans, not by me....

Comment: It´s "package br.com.bssotware.teste;"...
Not "import br.com.bssotware.teste;"

Comment: You are using Netbeans to write Android apps? Why?

Comment: No reason... I just like Netbeans...

Comment: Why I shouldn´t develop it on Netbeans?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this this line `import br.com.bssotware.teste.R;`.
Then clean and rebuild your project.

Comment: At the begining of the file put `package br.com.bssotware.teste;` instead of `"import br.com.bssotware.teste;`

Comment: I created another project. Instead of adding import br.com.bssotware.teste.R;, I´ve built it, then everything worked. In the end, somehow it was the mistake.